# Elegant way to identify runs inside a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I've run into this problem twice in the last two weeks alone, so I figured it's worth a post. I'm trying to identify "runs" inside a `data.table`, but I can't figure out an elegant way to do it.

### Example

```
set.seed(2016)
dt <- data.table(ID = 1:50, Char = sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE))
dt <- dt[order(Char, ID)]

    ID Char
 1:  9    A
 2: 10    B
 3: 20    C
 4: 42    C
 5:  2    D
 6:  4    D
 7:  6    D
 8: 18    D
 ...
```

Here, I'd like to identify and group rows where the ID is within 2 of the row above/below. Here's my currently ugly solution

```
# Runs of 2 or more IDs within 2 of each other
dt[, `:=`(InRun = FALSE, InRunStart = FALSE)]
dt[abs(ID - shift(ID, type="lag")) <= 2 | abs(shift(ID, type="lead") - ID) <= 2, InRun := TRUE]
dt[InRun == TRUE & abs(ID - shift(ID, type="lag")) > 2 | is.na(shift(ID, type="lag")), InRunStart := TRUE]
dt[InRun == TRUE, RunID := cumsum(InRunStart)]
dt[, c("InRun", "InRunStart") := NULL]
dt
    ID Char RunID
 1:  9    A     1
 2: 10    B     1
 3: 20    C    NA
 4: 42    C    NA
 5:  2    D     2
 6:  4    D     2
 7:  6    D     2
 8: 18    D    NA
 ...
```

Is there a better way to do this?

---

**EDIT:** It seems there's been some confusion over how I'm defining a "run".  To put it more explicitly, row_i and row_i+1 should have the same RunID if and only if their IDs are within a distance of 2.

Comment: Do you want those NA's there? Or can they count as another group?

Comment: Hmm, tough call.  Might as well keep them as NA to match my current work.

Comment: Ok, this isn't EXACTLY what you requested, but should do just fine for your purposes `dt[,InRun:=rleid(abs(ID-shift(ID,type="lag"))<=2 | abs(ID-shift(ID,type="lead"))<=2)];
dt[,InRun:=ifelse(!(abs(ID-shift(ID,type="lag"))<=2 | abs(ID-shift(ID,type="lead"))<=2),NA,InRun)]`

Comment: Basically, that second step puts the `NA`s in. So that's why you have the groups jump around. If you need the groups to be in order that might be harder.

Comment: Mike, I think there's a very subtle flaw to the solution you gave.  Consider two consecutive, but different runs.  I think your code will label them as the same run.  As an example, try your solution on this guy `dt <- data.table(ID = c(9, 10, 20, 21))`

Comment: Ok - so what you want is more nuanced than if the ID is within 2 of either the row above or the row below?

Comment: Not really.  To put it explicitly, row_i and row_i+1 should have the same RunID if and only if their IDs are within a distance of 2.

Comment: you can get the runs with `idx <- c(1, 1:(nrow(dt) - 1)); +(abs(diff(dt$ID))[idx] <= 2 | rev(abs(diff(rev(dt$ID)))[idx] <= 2))` and tease apart the consecutive ones by multiplying that vector by `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dt$ID) > 2))` (the numbering isnt consecutive but oh well) the you can -> ~~translate to data table ~~ <- which is an exercise i leave to the reader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stop after making this run ID:

```
dt[, run_id0 := 1L + cumsum(abs(ID - shift(ID, fill=ID[1L])) > 2)]
```

But to get the OP's run ID (which ignores length-one runs), here are a couple ways to go:

```
dt[duplicated(run_id0) | duplicated(run_id0, fromLast=TRUE), run_id1 := .GRP, by=run_id0 ]
# or
dt[, run_len := .N, by=run_id0 ][ run_len > 1L, run_id2 := .GRP, by=run_id0 ]
```

Comment: Still not sure if this is right, since the OP refers to looking both above and below the current row.

Comment: yours much nicer than mine by far :) nice

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks :) Pretty similar, really, just mine uses `shift` and does `cumsum` on the full T/F vec instead of the shorter `rle(vec)$values`. By the way, a common convention is `foo <- with(rle(x), ...)` so you don't have to define the rle object and refer to it with `$`s.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is elegant or not, but how about:

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(9, 10, 15, 18, 21, 22, 25))
run_ids <- abs(dt[1:(.N-1), ID] - dt[2:.N, ID]) <= 2
run_ids <- c(run_ids[1], run_ids)
foo <- with(rle(run_ids), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths))
foo[foo == 0] = foo[which(foo == 0) + 1]
dt[, RunID := foo]
dt[RunID == 0, RunID := NA]
#    ID RunID
# 1:  9     1
# 2: 10     1
# 3: 15    NA
# 4: 18    NA
# 5: 21     2
# 6: 22     2
# 7: 25    NA
```

Comment: This isn't right.  The first two rows should have the same RunID

Comment: think fixed... although it would probably fail if last is 0

Comment: Still fails.  See this example - `dt <- data.table(ID = c(10, 9, 7, 20, 21))`

Comment: hi, tried with the vector and i get `1  1 NA  2  2`, isn't that what you would like as output?

Comment: No.  7 is within 2 of the previous ID, 9, so they should have the same RunID.  See Frank's solution's output.

Comment: I think this is right.  Removing my down vote, but I'm not sure this is any simpler than my original solution.  Appreciate the effort and nice use of `rle`.

Comment: thx :) me neither if this is more "elegant" than yours but for sure the accepted answer is :)